# Google AppInvite: Quota Limit?

Tags: android, google-app-invites

I'm using Google Appinvite for Android and it works very well:
https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/

But I realized that a certain time of day any user can send the invites and after a few hours back to work.
I have a daily quota of submissions?
If so how do I increase?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any specific daily quota, but it does have spam and abuse monitoring. Normal activity is fine and shouldn't result in any type of daily restrictions.

Comment: I have many users and even send many invitations, around 10 000 per day.
I do not know if Google believes it is spam and for some time the shipment is paralyzed, and only returns within some hours.
What should I do to prevent this?